# How To Open EXE Files in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: software-recommendation

Please tell me how to open or access Exe files on Ubuntu 13.04 desktop.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot run them inside directly using Ubuntu (or any Linux distro for that matter) as they are designed to run on Windows DOS OS, but you CAN run some EXE's using this Ubuntu program called [WINE for Linux](http://www.winehq.org/download/ubuntu).

Repeating again, the scope of wine is limited. The EXE may not run or may run but not work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Wine or PlayOnLinux (I would recommend this one) from Ubuntu Software Center. Also worth attention is CrossOver software, but it isn't free.

Please notice that not all Windows programs are easy to run in Linux environment.

Answer (score 0):

WINE stands for Wine Is Not an Emulator, it is in fact a compatibility layer and is capable to run .EXE files in a Linux environment, by installing this you will be presented with a program which holds an icon displaying a wine glass containing red wine. Installing this will allow the use of many Windows-like programs, directories etc and is required for PlayOnLinux; be aware that WINE has limited capability and may run slower than that of a Windows machine but this is to be expected.

I used to run Steam using Wine and didn't achieve nearly the performance of that the Steam for Ubuntu provided. You may use:

```
sudo apt-get install wine
```